# change the cell view color when it select. And change it back when selected another cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an collection view cell.I each cell i have an view. As id now default, i set the border color of my view to `lightGray`.
So when ever i select any cell, i needs to change my view border color to red color. And again if i select any other new cell. My old cell view should change back to `lightGray`.And new cell view have to display as `redcolor`.

how can i do that :

in my cell :

```
    @IBOutlet var baseView: UIView! {
            didSet {
                baseView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                baseView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                baseView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            }
        }

 let datt = [["duration": "No", "price": "Rs. 100", "perMonth": "per month"],
                         ["duration": "12", "price": "Rs. 55.20", "perMonth": "per month"],
                         ["duration": "No", "price": "Rs. 1300", "perMonth": "one time"]]


     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "KMSubscriptionsCell", for: indexPath) as! KMSubscriptionsCell
        let subcription = subscriptions[indexPath.item]
        cell.durationLabel.text = datt["duration"]

     return cell
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! KMSubscriptionsCell
    cell.baseView.layer.borderColor = Utils.colorCode.selectedBorderColor.cgColor
                cell.baseView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0


            }
```

I tried some :

in my cell for row :

```
  if indexPath.item != indexPath.item {
    cell.baseView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.baseView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    }
```

its doesnt work.even i added in did select.No luck.Please help me out. How can i achive that.

Comment: what is your datasource? can you update your cell for row method code in your question?

Comment: as if now 3 cell wil be showing. i just hard code some values and i am making count of that cell. Cell is showing correctly. Only color of my new cell should get change. Only one shoudl be back to normal...

Comment: Ok you can achieve this by creating a class object and by adding one property says `isSelected` and you can keep track on selected cell.

Comment: is it possible with out class object. bec i can not create an model class for this.

Comment: its an middle part, and no more class wr i should not add.thats y

Comment: In that case you can add one key value pair in your `datt` object with every object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way is to use a property observer in the cell class:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = borderColor
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor
        }
    }

    private var borderColor: CGColor {
        return isSelected ? UIColor.red.cgColor : UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    }

}
```

Instead of the cell itself you can also apply the border to your `baseView` instead.

Comment: No needs to update anything in collection view did select methods ?. Any things need to set the `isSelected` value in cell for row or in did select method ?

Comment: No need to. Check it out.

Comment: Slotta can u please give ur suggestion on here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55255610/table-view-did-select-and-pass-the-index-to-change-the-page-menu-controller-tap